# Multithread celery worker for task division

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, celery

Im currently building an application that, based on some input, runs some scans.

The issue i'm encountering is that a bottleneck is being creating on some of the scans, I was wondering if there was a way to implement a different thread/worker for these tasks.

I'll ellaborate a little bit more.

I start my worker with the command

`pipenv run celery -A proj worker -B -l info`

```
### Tasks.py ###

@shared_task
def short_task_1():
    return

@shared_task
def short_task_2():
    return

@shared_task
def long_task_1():
    return
```

```
### handler.py ###
def handle_scan():
    short_task_1.delay()
    short_task_2.delay()
    long_task_1.delay()
```

A possible solution I find is assigning the short tasks to one worker and the longer ones to the other. But I cant find in the docs how to define which worker the task is assigned to with the `delay()` command.

Will having another worker for handling this tasks help? If another thread is the solution, whats the best way of doing it?

Comment: In general, you never schedule task to work on particular worker. - That is wrong way of thinking. (I learned it the hard way). Instead you create two queues, call them `long` and `quick`, and send tasks to these queues instead.

Comment: Thanks! After reading a little bit more I saw I had a misunderstanding on what workers and queues are for. Multiple queues should be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following

`delay()` does not work if you are trying to use multiple task queues. Mainly because `delay()` is only used if the "default" queue is used. For using multiple queues, `apply_async()` must be used.

For example, if a task was called with `.delay(arg1, arg2)`
Now (With multiple queues in mind) it needs to be called with `.apply_async(args=[arg1,arg2], queue='queue_name')`

So, here is how I did it finally, thanks to @DejanLekic
`tasks.py`

```
@shared_task
def short_task_1():
    return

@shared_task
def short_task_2():
    return

@shared_task
def long_task_1():
    return
```

Same as before. But here is the new handler

```
def handle_scan():
    # Fast queue with args if required
    short_task_1.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], queue='fast_queue')
    short_task_2.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], queue='fast_queue')
    # slow queue
    long_task_1.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], queue='slow_queue')
```

I start the workers by doing the following (mind the pipenv):

```
pipenv run celery -A proj worker -B --loglevel=info -Q slow_queue,fast_queue
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is very late, but you could've just specified the queue inside of the task decorator